# Smart Array P812 External ports don't detect backplane with SAS HDDs

Tags: hp-smart-array

I've found some articles that P812 do not see **SATA** drives via external ports after updating firmware 5.14 and above. But I can't find any mentions about restrictions with **SAS** hard drives. (I have two P812 controllers,1-st with firmware ver 5.70 and second with v. 6.x and neither see these two identical backplanes with SAS disks).
Why P812 do not see backplane with SAS hard drives and what to do to correct? Will downgrading firmware (at least temporarily) help to see the disks. I need to access information on those HDDs and I can't move disks to another server. Two internal ports are occupied. These two backplanes have worked fine via the same cables with SFF 8088 with LSI 9285CV-8e controller recently. The same model of backplanes works well with internal ports of P812 - so P812 is compatible with backplanes and HDDs. But P812 can't see them via external ports.

Comment: ???? This sounds very specific. Can you give better detail on what you need to do and why it has to be this way?

Comment: I need to access data on HDDs on these two backplanes via external ports of P812 controller (any of two P812 that reside on this server). The same model of backplanes work well with internal ports of P812. external ports do not see them. The only way I can access HDDs is to see them via external ports of P812.

Comment: This is not an issue of one P812 - both of controllers can't see any of two identical  backplane. And internal port of both P812 can see them.